# signed vs unsigned int in C

Tags: c, int

I am a C beginner and needed a quick clarification regarding ints.

When you cast something as an int, which is 32 bits, half of the bits are allocated for negative integers.  Thus, if you know that you will always have positive integers, casting something as an unsigned int should maximize your positive bits and thus make more sense when you know that output will always be positive.  Is this true?

Thank you!

Comment: "half of the bits are allocated for negative integers" isn't right. Half of the *range of values* is used for negative numbers, but this amounts to a single bit being used for "sign".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`half of the bits are allocated for negative integers` This statement is not true, one bit is allocated to the sign for regular ints.

However, you are correct in your assumption. If you are positive the number is positive, using `unsigned int` will allow you to access number in the range [0,2^32), while the regular int will only only allow [-(2^31),2^31-1], since you do not need the negative values, it leaves you with less positive numbers.

Comment: note that my answer assumes 32 bits ints, though it may be 16 bits, or 64 bits as well, the main idea behind the answer still applies for these cases.

Comment: amit, I must be ignorant or stupid or both. Could you please show me, in hexadecimal notation, the unsigned 32-bit integer that equals 2*32? Or the 16-bit integer that equals 2^16? or the 8-bit integer that equals 2^8? Thanks so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @PeteWilson: you cannot get to 2^32, this is why I wrote the range is `[0,2^32)` [without 2^32] and not `[0,2^32]` [with 2^32]. note the difference between `]` and `)` when writing range of numbers.

Comment: Ah, OK. So the range of an unsigned int is really 0,2^32-1. Now I understand. I didn't get that range notation.

Comment: @PeteWilson: yes. `[0,2^32)` == `[0,2^32-1]` for ints

Comment: OK, I hear a lot about "2's complement" arithmetic. Where does that 2's complement stuff fit in? If the high-order bit is 1 then then number is negative so 0x80000002 must be -2, right?

Answer (score 4):

Not half the *bits*, just *one* bit which translates to half of the *values*.  Also not *casting* but *declaring*:  If you *cast* something you are reinterpreting it which doesn't give you additional range, it just gives you a potentially different value than the original user intended.

Answer (score 3):

Only one bit is used to identify whether the number is positive or negative.

Casting to unsigned may or may not make sense.  Sometimes it's best to have debugger, et al, show the negative number, to make you aware that your number has gone out of range.

You especially need to be careful when comparing unsigned numbers -- many a loop has failed to terminate because the countdown value was unsigned and the compare was for < 0.

Comment: +1 primarily for the cautionary tale in the last sentence. :)

Answer (score 0):

One bit is used for +/-, not half.  Using unsigned numbers gives you double the range of positive values vs. the signed equivalent.

Comment: it doesn't double the number of values you can have, it doubles the number of *positive* values you can have.

Comment: But, of course, if you need that many values you're on the hairy edge to begin with and damn well better know what you're doing.