# Behavior of unsigned int in C

Tags: c, int, unsigned

The size of an **unsigned int** in C is `0 to 65,535 or 0 to 4,294,967,295`.

I tested with the following codes in C:

```
unsigned int number = 0;
number -= 300;
printf("%d\n", number);
```

**OUTPUT: -300**

I remember that if the value of `unsigned int` variable goes below 0, it should wrap around and I was expecting the output to be something like `4294966996`. However the output printed from the console is `-300`.

I tested similar statements in C++, it does give me `4294966996`.

**My question is:** Why is the output `-300` despite the fact that it is an `unsigned int`?

---

PS: I've looked through several posts with similar title, but they are not addressing the same issue:

[signed vs unsigned int in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562257/signed-vs-unsigned-int-in-c)

[Unexpected results on difference of unsigned ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985668/unexpected-results-on-difference-of-unsigned-ints)

Comment: `printf` is a dumb function. You have to make sure you are passing it the types it expects!

Comment: Do remember that Printing an unsigned int with signed int format string is undefined behavior.

Comment: Just one last question: Am I correct to say that, if I print it with %d, it will cast it implicitly into signed before printing?

Comment: I don't think there are requirements on how `printf` has to be implemented, it probably just aliases your arguments with a `char*` and parses the bytes into an appropriate c string (based on your format string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `printf("%d\n", number);` will print a signed value, even if the parameter is unsigned. Use `printf("%u\n", number);` for an unsigned value to be correctly printed.

Answer (score 3):

Just a bit of background to @UniCell's excellent answer.

The hardware stores an `int` and an `unsigned int` in exactly the same way. No difference. If you start adding to or subtracting from them, they will overflow and underflow in exactly the same way.

```
0xFFFFFFFF + 1 = 0
0 - 1 = 0xFFFFFFFF
```

If we consider the result as unsigned, `0xFFFFFFFF` means 4,294,967,295, otherwise it means -1. It's called 2's complement storage. Adding and subtracting are sign-agnostic. But multiplication and division are not, so there are usually different signed and unsigned machine instructions for these.

The type of these variables is only known for the compiler, not in runtime. `printf`'s parameters can be of any type, and the variables passed do not carry type-information in runtime. So you have to tell `printf` in the format string how to interpret them.

Comment: There is no guarantee, but in practice, it's always the case. And my practice includes the architectures Intel 196, Infineon C166, Freescale HCS12, Renesas, x86, x86_64 and ARM.