# Subtracting unsigned ints in C and getting -Wconversion warnings

Tags: c, gcc

Consider:

```
uint16_t x;
uint16_t y;

y = 0;
x = y - 1;
```

X will be some insane number.  [See other SO articles for the "why" and to learn about 2's compliment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055983/behavior-of-unsigned-int-in-c).

(I'm not asking why this is the case.  I know why. I'm asking something else. Read on.)

If you turn on the gcc flag -Wconversion, this perfectly valid C code above will throw `conversion to ‘uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may alter its value` That's the compiler trying to help us not mess up.  And I tend to program with such warnings turned on because they help me avoid messing up.

However, there are realistic cases where we might use an unsigned int as a counter and want to subtract 1 and NOT get this warning.  Also, we want to use it as a counter, get it down to zero and then just stop.  To do this in C, we have to put in some kind of a check. However, that kind of check code will run foul of the gcc warning.

Like the code above.

I want my cake and I want to eat it too.

What's the elegant solution for this?

Comment: Use explicit casting?

Comment: Just don't use narrow types for arithmetic. Their only reason of being is to save storage space.

Comment: @EugeneSh.NOPE.... use a proper unsigned literal (appending `U` to the literal string)  Using an explicit cast will silence the warning, but will not avoid the signed ot unsigned conversion, giving a possible altered result.

Answer (score 8):

Explicitly cast `y-1` to `uint16_t`. GCC is complaining not about the subtraction, but that you might lose information after the result of the expression is assigned to a (now smaller) type. (Integral operands are silently promoted to int when used in expressions, when the types are smaller and could fit in an signed int without losing precision.)

Comment: Actually, even unsigned narrow types are promoted to `int`, so you should omit your last half-sentence.

Answer (score 5):

In this code

```
x = y - 1;
```

The argument `y` is subject to ["default integer promotion"](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p11) per the C standard.

That means `y - 1` is an `int` value, and then that `int` result gets assigned back to a `uint16_t` via truncation.  That's what GCC is complaining about.

The way to fix the problem is to explicitly cast the result to `uint16_t`:

```
x = ( uint16_t ) ( y - 1 );
```

The full explanation can be found in [**6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1):

> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> - No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation.
> - The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision.
> - The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be
>     greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the
>     rank of signed char.
> - The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any.
> - The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended integer type with the same width.
> - The rank of char shall equal the rank of signed char and unsigned char.
> - The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.
> - The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the compatible integer type (see 6.7.2.2).
> - The rank of any extended signed integer type relative to another extended signed integer type with the same precision is
>     implementation-defined, but still subject to the other rules for
>     determining the integer conversion rank.
> - For all integer types T1, T2, and T3, if T1 has greater rank than T2 and T2 has greater rank than T3, then T1 has greater rank than T3.
>
> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>     the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> **If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>   integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.**
>
> **The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed
>   earlier, whether a "plain" char is treated as signed is
>   implementation-defined.**

Answer (score 3):

The expression:

```
x = y - 1;
```

Is affected by **integer promotion** as detailed in section 6.3.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>     the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by
>   the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>   integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.

Because `y` is of type `uint16_t`, which is of lower rank than an `int`, it is promoted to an `int`.  That is then subtracted by the constant 1, which also has type `int`, so the result of `y - 1` is of type `int`.  That value is then assigned to a `uint16_t` which is of lower rank than `int`, which is why you get the warning.

You need to cast the entire right hand side to `uint16_t` to avoid a warning:

```
x = (uint16_t)(y - 1);
```

Note that it is not enough to cast one or both operands of the `-` operator because the integer promotion rules will still go into effect anyway once a value of rank lower than `int` is used in a expression.

Comment: `x = (uint16_t)(y - 1);` is *exactly* what is compiled when you write `x = y - 1;` The lack of the warning is due to the splicit cast, but the problem remains there, see my answer for an explanation.